How to Connect and Query an External API in GridDB Using Python?
I am working on a project where I need to connect to an external API, retrieve data, and then store it in a GridDB container using Python. I am able to establish a connection to GridDB and create a container, but I am struggling with fetching data from the API and inserting it into GridDB efficiently.
Here are the specifics of my setup:
GridDB version: 4.5.0
Python version: 3.8
GridDB Python Client: Using griddb-python-client
API Endpoint: http://sandbox.stackcueprime.com/api/compliance
Data:
The API returns user data in the following JSON format:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "60d0fe4f5311236168a109ca",
            "title": "mr",
            "firstName": "Alill",
            "lastName": "Amditi",
            "email": "sales@jeem.net.sa"
        },

    ]
}

Code Attempt:
Here is my current attempt to fetch data from the API and insert it into GridDB:
import requestsfrom griddb_python import StoreFactory, ContainerInfo, ContainerType, GSException

Connect to GridDB

factory = StoreFactory.get_instance()gridstore = factory.get_store(host="192.168.0.158", port=31999,cluster_name="*", username="*", password="*")

Define container

con_info = ContainerInfo("ali_container",[["id", "STRING"], ["title", "STRING"], ["firstName", "STRING"], ["lastName", "STRING"], ["email", "STRING"]],ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)container = gridstore.put_container(con_info)

Fetch data from API

response = requests.get("http://sandbox.stackcueprime.com/api/compliance", headers={"app-id": "1114"})if response.status_code == 200:user_data = response.json()["data"]

# Insert data into GridDB
try:
    for user in user_data:
        container.put([user["id"], user["title"], user["firstName"], user["lastName"], user["email"]])
except GSException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
else:print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}")

Issue:

While fetching data from the API, I am unsure if I am handling the response correctly for inserting into GridDB.
Performance: The current approach seems slow for larger datasets. Are there any optimizations I can apply for better performance?
Error Handling: What are the best practices for handling errors during API requests and data insertion to ensure data consistency and integrity?
import requests
from griddb_python import StoreFactory, ContainerInfo, ContainerType, GSException

# Connect to GridDB
factory = StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host="192.168.0.158", port=31999,
    cluster_name="Ali", username="*", password="*"
)

# Define container
con_info = ContainerInfo("ali_container",
    [["id", "STRING"], ["title", "STRING"], ["firstName", "STRING"], ["lastName", "STRING"], ["email", "STRING"]],
    ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)
container = gridstore.put_container(con_info)

# Fetch data from API
response = requests.get("http://sandbox.stackcueprime.com/api/compliance ", headers={"app-id": "1114"})
if response.status_code == 200:
    user_data = response.json()["data"]

    # Insert data into GridDB
    try:
        for user in user_data:
            container.put([user["id"], user["title"], user["firstName"], user["lastName"], user["email"]])
    except GSException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}")

